# Implementing Emoticon in windows store chat

Tags: windows, xaml, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I am developing a Windows Store chat app.

In this apps, I am using a `TextBox` to receive message content from the user. I want to implement Emoticons (Smileys) such that typing a code gives a respective image inline with the text.

For example, for `:)`, I want to have a 'smile' image.

Answer (score 0):

What you'll need to do is use a [`RichTextBlock`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.richtextblock) to display your text. This will give you access to a adding in an `InlineUIContainer` block where necessary.

So, your process will be:

- Accept text in a regular text box
- Parse the text into a series of `Inline`s (`Run`, `InlineUIContainer`, etc)
- Create a new `Paragraph` for the message
- Add the `Inlines`s to the `Paragraph`.
- Add the `Paragraph` to your `RichTextBlock`'s `Blocks` property (a `BlockCollection`).

For each piece of text:

- `Split` the text, likely using `Regex`, searching for the keys which trigger an `Image` (':)', '(heart)', etc).
- For each non-image text, create a `Run` with the `Text` set to the text of the split
- For each `Image`, create an `InlineUIContainer` and an `Image`. Set the `Image` source to the proper `Image` path, then set the `Child` of the `InlineUIContainer` to the `Image`.
- Add the `Run` or `InlineUIContainer` the `Paragraph` via `Paragraph.Blocks.Add(Inline)`.

Certain icons may be included in the `Segoe UI Symbol` Font Family. If this is the case, you may choose to not use an `Image` for that symbol, and instead use a `Run` with the `FontFamily` set to `Segoe UI Symbol`. You can play around with the `FontSize` if you want them to be more prominent.

Hope this helps and happy coding!

Comment: Can you provide some of the useful links on this , i have search a lot  but is unable to get such useful links.

Comment: Mr.Nate Diamond finally i got the solution from process suggested by you , i am very much thankful for your kind suggestion.Your hopes comes true , it helps me ,happy coding. :)